# ElasticSearch Indexing data which i got from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, elasticsearch

I want to load the data to elasticsearch that i got from Sql Server and stored in list below c# entity object

```
public class c#entity
{
    public int CBMS_IMAGE_ID { get; set; }
    public string CBMS_DOC_ID { get; set; }
    public int CU_INVOICE_ID { get; set; }
    public string EXCEPTION_TYPE { get; set; }
}
```

the above list entity object is populated from sql server

How can I load that data to ElasticSearch so that i can perform searching from here instead of hitting database for every search filters

I tried this way in c#.net application

```
  List<entity> list = new List<entity>();

        list = LoadData();
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        client.Map<entity>(m => m
             .Index("entity")
             .AutoMap()
             );
```

I am not sure if my entity class data is moved to elasticsearch now, if so, how can i read on the asp.net page?

Comment: heave you ever tried Nest ? It has a BulkAll method for sending documents to elasticsearch.

Comment: thanks for reply ercyon, i can found help on sending documents to elasticsearch , but my requirement is sending data that got stored in c# entity list object to elastic search. -- please look into my edited comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to utilise Nest, the below should work... First set up a client using `var client = new ElasticClient(settings);`. I'd also recommend setting up a method next to determine whether or not to create your new index as shown below. Please replace Entity with the model you're looking to place into Elasticsearch

```
public void CreateIndexIfNotExists()
{
    var indexState = new IndexState();

    if (!client.IndexExists(IndexName).Exists)
        client.CreateIndex(IndexName, descriptor =>
            descriptor.Index(IndexName)
                .InitializeUsing(indexState)
                .Settings(SetupAnalysis)
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<Entity>(m => m.AutoMap())
                )
        );
}
```

Then you should hopefully be able to call the below bulk method to import your records into Elasticsearch. I'd recommend batching these requests up to call `client.Bulk` for every `X` number of entries and also implementing some kind of mapping layer to convert the SQL model to a model that works best for Elasticsearch (in case any of your concerns are different).

```
client.Bulk(b =>
    {
        foreach (var entity in col.ToList())
            b
                .Update<Entity>(u =>
                    u.DocAsUpsert(true)
                        .Id(entity.Id)
                        .Doc(entity)
                        .Index(IndexName));
        return b;
    }
)
```

Also, make sure that you've looked into the documentation around Id inference on Elasticsearch.

[Reference - Elasticsearch - Id Inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/Elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html)

Comment: Awesome John!! this works exactly the way i am looking into., few more questions                                                                                                             1. Will this elastic index data can be synced with SQL Server data and refreshed while performing search using elastic client as users may be perform updates in sql server while searching from elastic document within app.  ?       

2. where the index data will be stored physically in the .net applicaiton?

Comment: Hi Ram, 
1. You can bulk insert and query items in the index at the same time. 
2. No, indicies are persisted on the Elasticsearch server. If you're using the Nest client, your .Net application will be communicating with this server running outside of your .net app, with the data stored in a location described in the elasticsearch.yml file. This has the added benefit of being able to query the data from [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) or any other client capable of making requests to it's [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html).